# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $ f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^{3})}{x}$. Then f is not bounded and not uniformly continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $ f(x)=\frac{\sin(x^{3})}{x}$. Then which of the following is correct:

a)f is not bounded and not uniformly continuous

b)f is bounded and not uniformly continuous

c)f is not bounded and uniformly continuous

d)f is  bounded and  uniformly continuous

I think option a is correct $\because \sin{x}$ is bounded between $-1$ and $1$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ approches $\infty$ in neighborhood of zero.

This question was asked in TIFR 2019.

Comment: No, option (a) is not correct; the numerator vanishes at $0$ as well, and does so faster than the denominator.

Comment: yes , you are right then this becomes unbounded in $(0,\infty)$

Comment: @sejy No it doesn't. Think about what T. Bongers said - how could $\sin(x^3)/x$ be unbounded in $(0,+\infty)$. Can you show me an $x$ such that $\sin(x^3)/x=2$?

Comment: $-\frac{1}{x} < \frac{\sin{x^3}}{x} < \frac{1}{x}$ on $[1,\infty]$. All that's left is that pesky $(0,1)$ region.

Comment: A lot of confusion here.  This function is very well behaved, in fact $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x^3}{x} \, dx = \frac{\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function is bounded and uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$.

Clearly, $f$ is continuous and, hence, uniformly continuous on any compact interval $[a,b]$ with $a > 0$.

On the interval $(0,a]$ we have $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{\sin x^3}{x} = x^2\frac{\sin x^3}{x^3} \to 0\cdot 1 = 0 $ as $x \to  0$ and 
$f$ is extendible as a continuous function to the compact interval $[0,a]$, and, hence, uniformly continuous there.

On $[b, \infty)$, $f$ is uniformly continuous as well since $\displaystyle  |f(x)| = \frac{|\sin x^3|}{x} \leqslant \frac{1}{x} \to 0 $ as $x \to \infty$.

A continuous function that approaches a finite limit as $x \to \infty$ must be uniformly continuous -- proved many times on this site -- for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2905985/148510). This is also an interesting example of a function with an unbounded derivative that is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I mean, it is trivial to see that near $0$ you have $\sin(x^3)/x\sim x^3/x=x^2$, so it is definitely bounded there

Comment: @Federico You are right. before answering, i had to think twice.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Hey, cheer up!  ;)